# Find string inside string with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to parse a string to find certain values.

This is the initial string "gid_10_sid_1594177336",
I need the value of "gid" (10) and of "sid" (1594177336).

How I can do this inside a jquery script?

Comment: This isn't jQuery, but JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` function:

```
var str = 'gid_10_sid_1594177336'.split('_');
var gid = str[1];
var sid = str[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var input =  "gid_10_sid_1594177336";
var array = input.split("_");
var gid = array[1];
var sid= array[3];

alert(gid);
alert(sid);
```

Live example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AEeDk/)

Answer (score 0):

If the structure of the string is always:

```
var1_value1_var2_value2_...
```

Then you could use the `split` function (untested):

```
var current = "gid_10_sid_1594177336";
var tokens = current.split("_");

var gid = tokens[1];
var sid = tokens[3];
```

Reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Answer (score 0):

```
var strs = str.split('_')
```

is your best bet. This will create an array for you like so:

```
strs[0] = "gid"
strs[1] = "10"
strs[2] = "sid"
```